# show alert highlights for jQuery validation in bootstrap 3 tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I validate my form in bootstrap tabs using jquery [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) like this :

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("form[name=modify]").validate({
        highlight: function (label) {
            $(label).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            var fieldset = $(label).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
            if ($(fieldset).find("fieldset.tab-pane.active:has(div.has-error)").length == 0) {
                $(fieldset).find("fieldset.tab-pane:has(div.has-error)").each(function (index, tab) {
                    var id = $(tab).attr("id");
                    $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
                });

            }

        },

        debug: true,
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            first_name: {
                required: true,
            },
            surname: {
                required: true
            },
            id_number: {
                required: true
            },
            mobile_number: {
                number: true,
                minlength: 10,
            },
            home_number: {
                number: true,
                minlength: 10,
            },
            other_contact: {
                number: true,
                minlength: 10,
            },
            line1: {
                required: true,
            },
            city_town: {
                required: true,
            },
            postal_code: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
            },
            curr_renumeration: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
            },
            expect_renumeration: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            email: {
                email: true,
                required: true,
            },

        }
    });
    $("[type=submit]").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

in action jquery validation plugin worked and validate all tabs and show error bottom of each input. i need to show alert Or highlight title of tabs (ie : `<a data-toggle="tab" href="#form3">Address Details</a>`)  if in tabs was a error.

how do can i show this alert or highlight error in title tabs

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BoWw/cyPz6/25/)

Comment: Please explain your issue better.  You also do not need a `submit` handler function because the submit event is already captured by the plugin automatically.

Comment: @Sparky: please see this demo for another plugin : http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-tab/ when u click validate form, u see `X` in tabs title. i need to show error highlight or icon or .. in title tab when in tab is error for jquery validation in submit

Comment: I don't see anything like "validate form" on that page.

Comment: @Sparky: u don'e see tabs and form in bottom of page ?!

Comment: There is no "validate form" button in Safari because the "try it" section is blank.   I'm not sure I'd be using anything from that developer.  After all it's jQuery and should be working the same in all modern browsers.  (Although in Firefox, I see what you're talking about).

Comment: Ok, so what's the real problem here?  You don't understand what jQuery or CSS you need to put an "x" in the tab?  Or you didn't know that code would go inside the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions?

Comment: @Sparky: highlight and unhighlight tabs

Comment: Now you know.  Put your code within the `highlight` callback to mark the tab and put the reverse code in the `unhighlight` callback to un-mark the tab.

Comment: @Sparky: can u update my demo in jsfiddle?!

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're going to have to do the work of digging through that other site's code for yourself.  Once you figure out what code marks the tab, you would put it inside of `highlight` and then put the reverse code within `unhighlight`.

Comment: @Sparky: u see highlight function in my demo? i dont know how do find tabs for highlight function

Comment: I'm just not willing to invest the time into this one.  Inspect the code from [the demo page you showed me](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-tab/) and go from there.  Good luck.  Update your question showing more of your own effort and maybe I'll have more time later.